# OracleNetsuite - VAT Label shows wrong tax code

Tags: oracle, netsuite

I am using oracle netsuite erp where for sales order I have set the vat to 15%, the calculation of vat is according to 15%. When I print the sales order it shows 5% in it.
I have tried everything possible from changing the tax code to changing invoice preferences but the label in the sales order doesn't change.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "When I print the sales order it shows 5%" - is it, by any chance, hardcoded into the report?

Comment: I am very new to this system. I have no clue if that's the case.